# Upload a large number of files to AWS S3 at once

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3, file-upload

I have an app, That's arequired to upload more than `100,000 files` (`1MB` each) to `S3 Bucket`. I knew S3 has API for uploading a big file, but wonder if they have API for upload a large number of files.

I am currently using `putObject` and tried `upload` API to upload my files to S3. The problem is that it takes too long to upload (finish after browser timeout) and uses a lot of memory (which is more than `512MB` allowed limit).

The code for saving a file:

```
saveFile: async (fileUrl, data) => {
    await s3.putObject({
        Bucket: bucket,
        Key: fileUrl,
        Body: JSON.stringify(data)
    }).promise();
},
```

In another place, I put that `saveFile` in a loop like this:

```
for (let file of files) {
    await saveFile(file.url, file.data);
}
```

I searched for a solution and found out `stream` may help by reducing memory demand but I would like to know that is there any difference in term of time? and if it is, how can I achieve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I generally prefer to use the [managed upload API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#upload-property), instead of the putObject method. It handles large files with multiplart uploads, plus it has support for streams (you can't use streams with putObject, because that API needs the total file size).

For example, from Node:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new AWS.S3({});

s3.upload({
  Bucket: 'xxx',
  Key: 'fileName.png',
  Body: fs.createReadStream('/home/bar/Desktop/fileName.png')
}).promise(); // or callback
```

This will probably solve your memory-related issue, but probably it won't speed up the upload too much.
The problem with the `for` loop is that it will upload the objects serially, one after another. You could, at the opposite, use a `await Promise.all([/* your list*/].map(/* ... */))`, which will execute all the uploads in parallel - but - 100,000 is by far a too large number.

I suggest to use a library like [async](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#queue) which has a lot of useful methods for handling groups of async operations.
You could use, for example, the `cargo` or `queue` methods, and your code would look like:

```
const PARALLEL_UPLOADS = 10;
const q = async.queue((task, callback) => {
  s3.upload({
    Bucket: 'xxx',
    Key: task.dest,
    Body: fs.createReadStream(task.src)
  }, callback)
}, PARALLEL_UPLOADS);

q.drain = function() {
    console.log('all items have been processed');
};

q.push([
    { src: 'image1.png', dest: 'images/image1.png' },
    { src: 'image2.png', dest: 'images/image2.png' },
]);
```

This will upload all your files, up to 10 items concurrently.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thank you, Simone. It is very nice to know about [async](https://caolan.github.io/async/index.html) as I just use more js recently. Btw, nice explanation which I greatly appreciate. 

The above forEach you said, I think it should run in series instead, right? Or you mentioned forEach from any external lib/module?

Comment: PS: it now runs pretty fast, sometime reaches memory limit (1 or 2 times) but not as usual as using with nested putObject in a loop, while making use of what it has to run at its best. Very nice Simone!

Comment: Glad that I could help.
When I wrote `forEach`, I was actually referring to the normal `[ ].map`, wrapped in an `await Promise.all()`. This will result in a lot of requests to be made "in parallel", it does not wait for a request to finish to process the next one (because the await keyword doesn't make sense in it).
*answer above updated to refer to Promise.all instead of forEach*

Answer (score 0):

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const fs = require('graceful-fs'); // from node.js
const path = require('path'); // from node.js
const queue = require('async-promise-queue');
const s3 = new AWS.S3();

const pushS3 = (srcFolderPath, destFolderPath) => {
  const uploadPromise = [];
  console.log(`Pushing ${srcFolderPath} to S3`);

  const files = fs.readdirSync(srcFolderPath);
    if (!files || files.length === 0) throw new Error(`provided folder '${srcFolderPath}' is empty or does not exist.`);

  // for each file in the directory
  for (const fileName of files) {
    // get the full path of the file
    const filePath = path.join(srcFolderPath, fileName);

   // ignore if directory
   if (fs.lstatSync(filePath).isDirectory()) {
     continue;
   }

   uploadPromise.push({
     src: filePath,
     dest: `${destFolderPath}${fileName}`,
   });
  }
  const worker = queue.async.asyncify(task => s3.upload({
    Bucket: AWS_BUCKET,
    Key: task.dest,
    Body: fs.createReadStream(task.src),
  }).promise());

  return queue(worker, uploadPromise, 10000);
};

pushS3('sourcePath', 'destinationS3Path')
.then(()=>{console.log('Sucessfully Transferred to S3');})
.catch((err)=>{console.error(err);})
```

Promise implementation of the above Simone Lusenti's Solution. In my case, I had 50000+ odd files. I was trying to put those files to S3 from AWS ECS. I had 2 errors before. `EMFILE too many files open` error was solved by `graceful-fs` module and `Missing Credentials Error` in AWS ECS by using `async-promise-queue` module.